# Installing SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have two servers, a web server and a DB server.  The web server is going to be running SQL Server reports soon, and I need to install SQL Server Reporting Services.  My question is:

Does this get installed on the DB server, then the web server (.net code i guess?) talks to the SSRS server like a regular DB connect.

Or, does this get installed on the web server and gets its data from the DB.

Or, is part installed on the DB server, and part installed on the web server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reporting Services is installed on the database server, unless you want to buy another SQL license for the web server.

Then, the application uses the report viewer control (not a regular database connection) to communicate with the database / report server and display the reports.  The communication between the web server and the report server is done using HTTP.

In summary, the report viewer control in the web application calls the SSRS web service on the database server.  SSRS then queries the data from the database and returns the report to the report viewer which renders it for display.

Comment: I actually have another question:  You said they communicate via HTTP (port 80).  Both servers have outgoing port 80 disabled.  DB server has both outgoing and incoming 80 disabled.  Web server has incoming 80 disabled as well (it only allows HTTPS connections (443)).  In this type of setup, will SSRS fail?

Comment: @tcarter2005: Allowing only HTTPS on the web server is fine because that is the communication between the client and web server.  By default, SSRS uses port 80, but can be configured to use SSL.  Communication with SSRS is through HTTP(S), but it's up to you how to configure it.  Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345223.aspx

Comment: The SSRS web app, which is also the basis for web services, is installed using IIS, which by default listens on port 80. Since this should be the only usage of IIS on the DB server, you can tell IIS to listen for requests on a different port. However, unless the DB server is publicly accessible (which should be avoided in most circumstances), you should be able to have port 80 open in the LAN while keeping it closed at the firewall. Depends on your topology.